# Uniqueness of a extension fuctional on $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Consider $(C[0,1];||.||_{\infty})$ and define the fuctional $f:\langle t\rangle \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$f(\alpha t)=\alpha.$$
It's easy to see that $||f||_{\infty}=1$, so by Hahn-Banach theorem I have a extension $F$ of $f$ to all $C[0,1]$ such that $||F||=1$.

But is this extension unique? (the only result involving uniqueness of Hahn-Banach Extensions I know is for strictly convex spaces and $C[0,1]^*$ isn't strictly convex).

Comment: I suspect that the answer is yes, and that this can somehow be shown as a consequence of the [Radon Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem).

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that $F(g) = g(1)$ is one such extension.

Comment: Note that the function whose span we consider is important.  For instance, if we defined a similar map on $\langle 4(t-1/2)^2\rangle$, then the maps $g \mapsto g(0)$ and $g \mapsto g(1)$ are both valid extensions.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  thats true! I tried to create 2 extensions on $\langle t, t^2 \rangle$, but I couldn't find 2 such that the norm is still 1

Comment: Instead of the R-N theorem, [this characterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#The_dual_space_C[a,_b]*) of $C[0,1]^*$ (hopefully correct) seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi \in C([0,1])$ be any continuous function which vanishes on some interval $[1-\delta, 1]$.  If $F(\varphi) \ne 0$, then by considering the function $\psi(t) = t \pm \epsilon \varphi(t)$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, we will have $\|\psi\|_\infty \le 1$ but $F(\psi) > 1$, contradicting $\|F\|=1$.  So we conclude $F(\varphi) = 0$ for all such $\varphi$.

Now suppose that $\varphi \in C([0,1])$ with $\varphi(1) = 0$.  We can find a sequence of continuous functions $\varphi_n$ vanishing on $[1-\delta_n, 1]$, with $\varphi_n \to \varphi$ uniformly.  Then by the continuity of $F$ we conclude $F(\varphi)=0$ in this case also.

Finally let $u \in C([0,1])$ be arbitrary.  Let $\varphi(t) = u(t) - u(1) t$, so that $u(t) = \varphi(t) + u(1) t$.  Then $\varphi(1) = 0$ and so $F(\varphi) = 0$ as previously argued.  By linearity of $F$ we conclude $F(u) = u(1)$.

So the only possibility for $F$ is $F(u)=u(1)$, and $F$ is indeed unique.

Comment: what a Beautiful solution! thanks @Nate Eldredge!!